# numpy meshgrid resizing of test data

Tags: python, numpy, mesh

I have a test dataset with a shape of (100, 49280)

I am trying to plot the data from an svm classification, based on the example in http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html like so:

```
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
```

So I print x_min, x_max, h, y_min, y_max:

-0.6541590243577957

7.5925517082214355

0.02

-0.9953588843345642

4.58396577835083

so far so good, according to what I have found in the docs I expect to get a mesh array with these values.

just to check I print xx and yy and get:

```
(279, 413)
(279, 413)
```

which seems fishy. and when I get to the line:

```
Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

I get the error: ValueError: X.shape[1] = 2 should be equal to 49280, the number of features at training time

I have never used numpy's meshgrid function but everything I have read in the docs seems normal and well documented as most of numpy is. I am sure that I am missing something silly but for the life of me I can't find it. Does anyone have an idea of where I went wrong? I will try to make a more informative title for the question once I figure out what the problem is too.

Answer (score 0):

The `np.arange` function does not fit to this scenario. You probably want to use `np.linspace` as follows

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x_min, x_max), np.linspace(y_min, y_max))
```

The docpage for `np.linspace`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Would you mind explaining why "The np.arange function does not fit to this scenario"? Thanks

Comment: I assume this has to due with the high dimensionality but I would like to understand better why it doesn't work.  btw linspace changes my size to (50, 50) but still I get the same error in the end

Comment: 'When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases.' This is from the documentation of np.arange . I lack the knowledge to explain why is that so. Did using np.linspace solve your problem?

Comment: That is helpful and no, it seems to make more sense but the error is still the same.  I will read the docs you provided and see if I can advance here.